# If f: [0, 1[ -> R continuous with f(0) = 0 and f(x) > 0 for x > 0 and limx-1(1/f(x) = 0, for every c >0 existence of a such that f(a) > c

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: [0, 1[ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous with the following properties:

1: $f(0) = 0$

2: $f(x) > 0 \space \text{for} \space x > 0$

3: $\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{1}{f(x)} = 0$

a) Prove that for every $c > 0$ there exists a $a \in [0, 1[$ such that f(a) > c.

b) Prove that $f([0, 1[) = [0, \infty [$.

So intuitively this seems pretty clear to me, yet I do not know how to construct a rigorous proof. This is what I was thinking:

Since $\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{1}{f(x)} = 0$ we know that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that if $|x-1|<\delta$ then $|\frac{1}{f(x)}|< \epsilon$. So I was thinking we can choose $\epsilon$ to be $\frac{1}{c}$. The existence of the limit ensures that there exists a $\delta$ for this epsilon. I feel like I need to define $a$ in terms of this $\delta$, but this is where I get stuck.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just say "take $a \in ]1-\delta, 1[$."

Comment: "Proof" is a noun, not a verb.

Comment: Haha thanks, that's what happens after a 6 hour lib session

Comment: So if you take $a \in ]1 -\delta, 1[$ how do you know that $a \in [0, 1[$?

Comment: First make sure $\delta \leq 1$. When you apply the definition of limit, you can always select a smaller $\delta$ than the one the definition provides.

Answer (score 1):

By contraposition, assume the negation :

**hint for a)**

$$(\exists c>0) \;:\; (\forall x\in [0,1 [) \; 0 <f (x)\le c $$

then
$$(\forall x\in[0,1 [) \; \; \frac {1}{f (x)}\geq \frac {1}{c} $$

$$\implies \lim_{x\to 1^-}\frac {1}{f (x)}\geq \frac {1}{c}>0$$
and this is in contradiction with $$\lim_{1^-}\frac {1}{f (x)}=0$$.

**for b)**

$f $ is a positive  unbounded function (by a) ) with $f (0)=0$ thus $f ([0,1 [)=[0,+\infty) $.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f(x)>0$ for $0<x<1$, you can prove that
$$
\lim_{x\to1^-}f(x)=\infty
$$
Fix $M>0$. By assumption, there exists $\delta>0$ (and it's not restrictive to assume also $\delta<1$) such that, for $1-\delta<x<1$,
$$
\left|\frac{1}{f(x)}-0\right|<\frac{1}{M}
$$
which is the same as saying $f(x)>M$.

Now let $c>0$. Then, for $M=c$, choose $\delta$ with $0<\delta<1$ such that, for $1-\delta<x<1$, $f(x)>c$. Pick $a$ with $1-\delta<a<1$; then $f(a)>c$.

Finally apply the intermediate value theorem to $f$ over $[0,a]$.